Issue with using IP address SSL
Mongod database with Nginx.
I am getting this error when connected to my database.
http://212.38.94.32:3001/api/
"This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS".
I have a domain SSL encrypted by this IP.
What is the solution for this error and how can I connect using SSL to my specific IP?

The error means the name you are connecting to (212.38.94.32) is not in the certificate.

Did you read the error message? Did you read the connection string? Not to be rude, but we generally expect that people attempt solving their problems, and not just cut'n'paste error messages into the question box.


http://212.38.94.32:3001/api/
"This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS".

Don't you see a discrepancy? I do: you are attempting to connect using http:// which is not HTTPS. Use the https:// URL scheme.

I have a domain SSL encrypted by this IP.

This is meaningless. I have a very strong doubt that you have an SSL certificate which is made valid for the IP (that's possible but very rare and I had never seen such certificates signed by public CAs). Instead of literal IP address you must use your server's host name (which also has to be mentioned in a SSL certificate in a subjectAltName filed), for SSL certificate validation to work. So, your connection URL must be of the form:
https://yourserver.example.org:3001/api/

and the certificate must be valid for either yourserver.example.org or *.example.org (a wildcard). Such a certificate can be easily obtained from Let's Encrypt or ZeroSSL.

Thanks for your valuable feedback.
It works with domain name

Granted you have followed the relevant documentation and have build mongod with --ssl, and how to load the perhaps free Let's Encrypt SSL certificate in your cluster set, you now only need to require SSL in your connection string.
But I personally would never expose MongoDB over the internet. I would have a RESTful API querying the collections and put the SSL certificate on the API, not on the cluster set.
Best of luck figuring this out!
